# Global database between 2 different application(ASP.net web app and window form application)

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want  to share database between 2 different application as i mentioned early(web app and window app.)  so how can i do that in .net framework??

Comment: use transactions in all of your SQL queries or use entity frame work, as it involves transactions by default

Answer (score 0):

Well, a good way to implement this would be to have a service based layer that includes business rules and data access. These services will communicate with both the clients.

Comment: heyy can you tell me how to implement same ??